# Why does rvest/html_table skip every second row in this table?

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape this table but for some reason every second row is skipped (which means I don't have data on half of the states). This is my code:

```
# read in the url
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
webpage <- read_html ("https://oui.doleta.gov/unemploy/trigger/2013/trig_010613.html")
df <- webpage %>%
html_node("table") %>%      
html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is? The only thing I can think of is that every second row has background colour specified?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps

```
webpage <- read_html("https://oui.doleta.gov/unemploy/trigger/2013/trig_010613.html")
df <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/table') %>%      
  html_table(fill = TRUE) 


d = as.data.frame(df)
```

Comment: Thanks but it still has the same problem where every second row is missing :(